# Issues with IDLE

Tags: python, idle-python

I can't run programs with IDLE or any files saved with IDLE. I get a syntax error. I was just testing it out with `print "Hello World"`. This is the message I am receiving

```
File "p.py", line 1
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 16:38:10) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is it reading the title? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the interactive interpreter's header into the file. This is not required, and wont work.

E.g.: You open a `python` shell and do this:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "Hello world!"
Hello world!
>>>
```

The above is made up of:

- The standard header, this is printed each time you start the shell:

  ```
  Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
  [GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  ```
- The an entered command: To use this in a file, you **remove** the `>>>` prefix.

  ```
  >>> print "Hello world!"
  ```
- The printed output: This is distinct in that it doesn't start with `>>>`.

  ```
  Hello world!
  ```
- A new prompt, for you to type in:

  ```
  >>>
  ```

So, if you were to make a file which runs the commands as you did in the above interactive session, you would simply use:

```
print "Hello world!"
```